# Make a PUT / DELETE non ajax service call from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I am new to javascript, I want to make a service call which deletes a record from the DB. I am able to make a GET / POST call but am not able to make a DELETE call from my script.

**As per my requirement I do not want to make an ajax call**. Below is my code snippet, please suggest

```
$.delete('http://localhost:3000/remove/'+friendName,{},function(response){     
}).error(function(){});
```

Comment: Just to be sure. By ajax, you mean async right? And that you want this to be in sync?

Comment: What... what kind of call do you *want* to make?!

Comment: You can't directly make a javascript-based PUT or DELETE request without AJAX, it's not possible. Also, your code snippet _is_ AJAX...

Comment: I want a synchronous call to a delete service

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing $.delete in jquery. You need to create a $.ajax request with correct type

```
$.ajax({
   url: '{url goes here}',
   type: 'DELETE',
   success: function(result) {
       // Do something with the result
   } 
});
```

Comment: And make it async false so it becomes synchronous call?

Comment: async:false is no longer supported with browsers. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated

Comment: @serdar.sanri The deprecation is with `Deferred`, not with `success`/etc. callbacks.

Comment: I knew it's deprecated but did not know its no longer supported by browsers

Comment: `Note: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: Right, deprecated, not unsupported, for now.

Comment: If I can't have async:false and I use $.delete, please help me with some mechanism to have a synchronous call for this